# How to allow terminal app read ALT and other keys?

Tags: terminal

How to enable `Alt` key, `Control-Left`, `Control-F1`, `Alt-S`, `Shift-End` and other *"impossible"* keyboard combinations in the terminal applications?

Is this at all possible? I was thinking about `TERMINFO` and `TARMCAP`, maybe I need to install and user other terminal emulators rather than *xterm*, *xterm-256color* and *vt100*? I know *xterm-256color* extends *xterm* to support 256 colors, maybe you can do the similar thing with the keyboard.

I am not talking about X keyboard access.

Comment: What language are you using?